# How to debug by reviewing Heroku logs ? (beginner of RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

I pushed my project to heroku and opened the app. However, it came out the "Application error", and noticed me to check logs for details.

I input the "heroku logs" in iTerm, but I can not understand where is the problem? and how to read the logs?

[heroku logs-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC0fN.jpg)

[heroku logs-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wimq.jpg)

[heroku logs-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCHEv.jpg)

Comment: What database are you using? Try tu run ‘heroku run:detached rake db:migrate’

Comment: please tell us you have run your app locally with `bin/rails server`, right? it sounds like you think you have to push to Heroku before debugging

Comment: Please do not post pictures. If you would like us to review your logs, please be so kind as to post the **text** of those logs into the body of your question (with proper formatting, please).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the error details like the app displays in development mode, you can add `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`  in your config/environments/production.rb and then push again on heroku.